# JupyterLab(1.2.6) can't find module 'plotly'

Tags: python, anaconda, plotly, conda, jupyter-lab

I'm getting this error:
[image: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly']

Which I find weird because:
[image: Anaconda showing plotly 4.10.0]

Before getting to this point I ran these two commands, since my plots didn't show up. I just had blank cells:
[image]

I'm following a python boot camp from udemy and I'm trying my best to follow along with the instructor. Looking at the draft suggestions on the right, I'm not sure if I've provided enough code to reproduce the example. I've looked through the list of similar questions and I can't find anything that looks useful to my particular situation.

Deleting JupyterLab and the notebook, then reinstalling and beginning a new book pushes the "ModuleNotFoundError" down a line further:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cufflinks'
```

Reinstalling cufflinks with the following command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge cufflinks-py
```

lands me back where I started. Plots not showing. These problems only seems to happen in JupyterLab, JupyterNotebook is fine and PyCharm doesn't show any errors either, but I can't figure out how to plot from PyCharm.

Best regards,

Jacob Collstrup

Comment: Are you using the same environmet in jupyter lab on which plotly is installed? It seems like you are using base environment and installation is made in environment named DataScience.

Comment: I don't know. I'm reasonably convinced I'm using the right environment, as I specfically installed jupyterlab in that environment and had it selected when I started jupyterlab.

How do I check that jupyterlab is running from the correct environment?

Comment: In the first image posted in your question look at the top right corner. You can see Python 3 as the selected environment. Click it and change it to DataScience and then rerun the code. It should do the job.

Comment: I can't find the right kernel in the drop-down menu:
[link](https://photos.app.goo.gl/HdyZxLrXJMUhz6N67)

It should use the one called "DataScience" from Anaconda. I don't know why it doesn't. After creating the "DataScience" environment in Anaconda, I installed jupyterlabs, using Anaconda, while that environment was selected...

Comment: I have mentioned the steps in the answer. Please check to add the environment to the jupyter lab.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to add the kernal to jupyter lab or notebook:

1. Open command prompt and activate the environment: `conda activate DataScience`
2. Install ipython kernel to this environment: `conda install ipykernel`
3. Add this environment to Jupyter lab using: `ipython kernel install --user --name=DataScience`

Finally, open Jupyter lab and respective file. You change then change the environment from top right corner.